# Usage of TimedText APIs in Media Player API 16

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Has anyone had luck using the TimedText apis in the Media Player on Android API 16?

We are using an external SRT subrip file that is stored in the app's getFilesDir() storage area. Whenever we pass it to MediaPLayer via addTimedTextSource, we get a cryptic exception:

```
12-20 14:17:11.581: W/System.err(693): java.lang.RuntimeException: failure code: -38
12-20 14:17:11.581: W/System.err(693):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.invoke(MediaPlayer.java:644)
12-20 14:17:11.591: W/System.err(693):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.addTimedTextSource(MediaPlayer.java:1812)
12-20 14:17:11.591: W/System.err(693):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.addTimedTextSource(MediaPlayer.java:1776)
12-20 14:17:11.591: W/System.err(693):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.addTimedTextSource(MediaPlayer.java:1708)
```

We've tried several files that are known to work on other players just fine.

Comment: hi, can u share the code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently supported format is SubRip with the file extension .srt
You can download demo [TimedTextTest](https://github.com/iTech-Developer/TimedTextTest.git)